# Java linked queue

Tags: java

I keep getting this error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

and i dont know what im doing wrong.

It is occuring in the line `end.setNext(n);`

This happens in my main class when i try to put a number into `pushEnd`.

It only occurs after I have added a number previously to it.I know that the error basically means that I am pointing at nothing, but isnt it saying that when the list is not empty, back is now n? Any help is appreciated.

Also, begin and end representthe opposite ends of the link. Like a deque

```
 public void pushEnd(T value)
    {
        Node n = new Node<T>(value);

        if(!isEmpty())
            end.setNext(n);
        else
            begin = n;

        end = n;
        size++;  
    }
```

Comment: where on earth is `end` being defined or intialised?  I guess your isEmpty may not be retuning what you think or `end` is being set back to null.

Comment: At the top of the class. Sorry i didnt want to post a huge code...:(

Comment: the entire code is needed,otherwise can not see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for not posting a huge amount of code, but maybe you are missing some important stuff.